# How to solve for f?

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation

The question asks to solve for the variable: 
$$2=6(3^{4f-2})$$

I am not quite sure how to solve for $f$ because the bases on either side cannot be made equal. Here is an example of a similar equation that I was able to understand:
$$2(4^{v+1})=1$$
$$2[(2^{2})^{v+1}]=2^{0}$$
$$2(2^{2v+3})=2^{0}$$

$$\therefore2v+3=0$$
$$2v=-3$$
$$2v=-3\over2$$
$$v=-3\over2$$

Comment: Which techniques are you supposed to use? Perhaps add that to your question.

Comment: *HINT:* If you divide both sides by $3$ you will get:$$\frac{1}{3}=3^{4f-2}$$Now just rewrite $\frac{1}{3}$ as $3^?$ and then compare indexes to solve

Comment: @Mufasa Wouldn't it be $2\over3$ instead of $1\over3$?

Comment: @DunjaElez - Your question was:$$2=6(3^{4f-2})$$Divide both sides by $6$ to get:$$\require{cancel}\frac{2}{6}=\frac{\cancel{6}(3^{4f-2})}{\cancel{6}}$$Hence:$$\frac{1}{3}=3^{4f-2}$$

Comment: @Mufasa So you meant divide by 6 instead of 3.

Comment: Oops! Sorry - my mistake - you are right - well spotted! :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the bases on each side to be equal to solve this problem. First let's clean up the RHS as much as possible. $$2=6(3^{4f-2}) = 6(3^{4f}3^{-2}) = 6((3^{f})^4 3^{-2})$$ The properties I used were: $a^{xy} = (a^{x})^{y}$  and $a^{b+c} = a^ba^c$ for a base $a$. Dividing  both sides of our equation by $6$ yields $$\begin{align} \implies \frac{1}{3} =(3^{f})^4 3^{-2} \\ \implies 3 = (3^{f})^4 \\ \implies \sqrt[4]{3} = 3^f \\ \implies \log_3\left(\sqrt[4]{3}\right)=f \end{align}$$  Now can you apply logarithm properties to simplify $\log_3\left(\sqrt[4]{3}\right)$? Things will cancel quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, it can be written as
\begin{equation}
3^{-1} = 3^{4f-2}
\end{equation}
and hence $4f-2=-1$

Comment: You are correct, but I would suggest explaining what you did to obtain $3^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

you can factor the $6$ on the right hand side and rewrite your equations as $$2 = 2 \times 3 \times 3^{4f-2} \to 1 = 3^{4f-1}\to 4f = 1\to f = \frac 14. $$